# Access Django variable on a page from separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, django

I have searched SO regarding this topic without much success and I hope this is not a duplicate after you go through the entire problem description.

Let me say I have a variable `countryList`, a JSON text, returned from Django view context to the template and I inserted it directly into the body:

```
<body>
  {% if countryList %}
  [Blocks for other codes]
  {% endif %}
</body>
```

What I found is that if I want to access the content/value of `countryList` from a JavaScript(JS), I have to place this JS code inside the `[Blocks for other codes]`. In this way, I can directly access the content via, for example `var cList = '{{ countryList }}';` inside a `jQuery(document).ready()` function.

However, I attempt to access the same variable from an external JavaScript file (`country.js`) loaded to this HTML in the following way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'country.js' %}"></script>
<body>
  {% if countryList %}
  [Blocks for other codes]
  {% endif %}
</body>
```

then using `var cList = '{{ countryList }}';` inside this file only gives me a string variable `{{ countryList }}`.

There is no issue with Django settings and the `country.js` can be loaded properly. This makes me wondering if it has something to do with the scope. I understand that Django variables of such are directly inserted into the HTML as text. Then, where on this HTML page does such a variable reside? How can I access it from a JS file loaded to this page?

Note added: I am aware of that I can insert a script into `[Blocks for other codes]` to store this variable to local or session storage and then allow it to be accessed from JS file. But I intend to do it in just one file.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax? If you want to have variables in JS ajax call to server is the best way.

Comment: @giaco: Yes, in principle I agree with you fully. One problem I have to AJAX call is the asynchronous nature which incurs more data traffic between client and server if this variable is repeated used. I want to save this variable locally. But it appears that I have insert a separate price of code between `{% if %}` and `{% endif %}`. I prefer to have all logics in one JS file.

Comment: I understand what do you mean. What are you trying to achieve is bad practice. I would go with either Django template rendering(in case you can live without data in javascript) or ajax calls to fetch and show all data(no data rendering).

Comment: @giaco: Must say that is a good advise. I however have to live with this temporarily before an overhaul.

Comment: If you have heavy front-end app I would suggest you to use some front-end framework like Angular/React/Vue and to separate front-end completely. But if you are building simple CRUD app then I wouldn't complicate things with too much javascript calls for data(it quickly becomes spaghetti code).